# non-linear lower bounds for polynomial time decision problems

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, lower-bounds

Are there any decision problems that have deterministic polynomial time algorithms and proven non-linear lower bounds?

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/147968/755

Comment: thanks for the link. that answers my question.